# Is there any possibility to fully customize angular material table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to customize the angular material table so that I can display image, link, dropdown, and action buttons dynamically in the table.

I am not sure if Angular provides customization at such a level or not. I researched for customization. Unfortunately, I did not find any luck.

If someone can help me to understand that is it really possible to customize angular material table at such level and if we can customize it then how can I implement it?

Comment: You will probably need to create custom components like mat-custom-dropdown etc. and create configuration service in wich you will specify what elements are you passing to the table. Then in some layout component with table you will need to handle all data from service. And yeah angular material dont provide such customization, but with all components togheter you can create something usefull.

Comment: I was thinking the same way that I can get similar UI using other material components. However, I wanted to know that I can modify an existing table component or not.

Comment: I guess if there is no option in API of material table, than you simply cant do that with just a table.

Answer (score 1):

I've prepared [a code example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6yww4m) that would be helpfull.

It's material table creaded by [material schematics](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics) with little modifications to be more configurable.
The table needs list items, columns config and general config.

Maybe it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use other component like button, toggle buttons inside table.
See code below

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatTableModule, MatButtonModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} 
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button></td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcglav)

Let me know if you have any doubt.